# Safari CORS issue - host not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin

Tags: safari, cors, access-control

Hi I am having an issue with CORS on safari. My request is working fine in every other browser except safari. I keep getting the error message `[host] not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin` although the api specifically sets the request url in the response for both the OPTIONS request and the POST request.

I have researched this endlessly but nothing I have found has worked.

I have attached a screenshot from chrome which you can see all of the request and response headers and a screenshot from Safari where you can see the error. It is exactly the same request with exactly the same parameters.

Chrome: 
[image: Chrome headers] 
Safari:
[image: Safari Headers]

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score -2):

Cross Origin Resource Sharing calls are generally blocked by browsers and thus API calls made from a website (in your case localhost:3004) to a remote host 52.85.173.227 (I think you have hosted it in Amazon's API Gateway).

What you need to do to enable CORS .

1. If you are using AMazon's API Gateway .

   - Click on the resources and in the Action , you have an option where you can enable CORS . Do that and it will add the headers to enable CORS .

[Option on AWS API Gateway to enable CORS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vPuiC.png)

Once you do this your response header of OPTIONS call will have "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" as "*" .

Thus your browser / web site will be able to make cross origin calls.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks. Yeah we already have CORS set on the API Gateway. If there was a sepcific CORS issue then surely it would not work in Chrome, FF, IE etc. The problem is that it is just Safari that it wont work on, everything else is fine.

Comment: @danwoodbury 3 years on, did you ever figure out the issue? I am facing this bizarre problem where Safari will successfully complete 1 request, then block ALL subsequent requests made from that device. Smells like a cookie-related issue to me, but I cannot figure out how to resolve it.